# how to check the date is not greater than today with ajax calendar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, date, compare

I have applied ajax calendar on a textbox and applied the following check on its selection

```
 function checkDate(sender, args) {
        if (sender._selectedDate > new Date()) {
            alert("You cannot select a day future than today!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            // set the date back to the current date
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
        }
    }
```

My html code is:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" Width="140px" MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxctrl:calendarextender onclientdateselectionchanged="checkDate" id="cale_txtDOB"
                                runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDOB" format="MM/dd/yyyy" cssclass="cal_Theme1">
                            </ajaxctrl:calendarextender>
```

Its working fine but if i enter the date manually then this is not working, how can i make both ways work for me.

means if user enters it manually then it also check the date and when user select it from calendar then it also validate the date.

Answer (score 1):

This is your modified javascript function:

```
    function checkDate(sender, args) {
        //alert(sender._selectedDate > new Date());
        if (sender._selectedDate > new Date()) {
            alert("You cannot select a day future than today!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            // set the date back to the current date
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is a new javascript functio, just add it beneath your function:

```
    function checkDate1(txt) {
        if (new Date(txt.value) > new Date()) {
            alert("You cannot select a day future than today!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now go to your Page_Load event of the page, and add this line of code:

```
    this.txt.Attributes.Add("onblur", "checkDate1(this);");
```

You may change these function names, as I just wrote this for you in a bit hurry. Didn't get much time to test it well too. Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [jQuery Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method ?

```
$('#textBoxName').change( function() {
  if ($(this).val() > new Date()) {
     alert("You cannot select a day future than today!");
       var today=new Date();
       $('#textBoxName').val(today);
  }
});
```